# Implementing an atomic reference count where only the last one drops with acquire semantics

Tags: synchronization, rust

I just finished watching both parts of Herb Sutter's 2012 C++ and Beyond talk about atomics. In it [he mentions](https://youtu.be/KeLBd2EJLOU?t=5018) that they initially shipped with a bug where the atomic reference count type only guarded the delete behavior with `release` semantics when actually it needs to be `acq_rel`, but to me it seems like actually only the last one to drop needs to bother with acquiring. The others *can* get away with release.
I tried implementing this in Rust (because unlike in his talk, this is the year 2023 and we have better tools today), but it was a bit tricky. Is this correct? Is it performant? Do atomic reference counts today do this? (I assume so since copilot gave this as an autocompletion)

```
use std::{
    ops::Deref,
    sync::atomic::{fence, AtomicUsize, Ordering},
};

pub struct MyArc<T>(*mut MyArcInner<T>);

struct MyArcInner<T> {
    value: T,
    count: AtomicUsize,
}

impl<T> MyArc<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        let inner = Box::into_raw(Box::new(MyArcInner {
            value,
            count: AtomicUsize::new(1),
        }));
        Self(inner)
    }
}

impl<T> Clone for MyArc<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let inner = self.0.as_ref().unwrap();
            inner.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
            Self(self.0)
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Deref for MyArc<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { &self.0.as_ref().unwrap().value }
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for MyArc<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let inner = self.0.as_ref().unwrap();
            if inner.count.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::Release) == 1 {
                fence(Ordering::Acquire);
                drop(Box::from_raw(self.0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```